# Can と、に sometimes be Interchanged in a sentence? 彼は円をドルに/と両替した。

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-と

> 彼は円をドルに両替した。
> He exchanged yen for dollars.
> 彼は円をドルと交換した。
> He exchanged yen for dollars.

I am not sure I understand why in one sentence に is used yet in the second sentence と  is used.  Could と and に be used interchangeably in this situation?  Would the meaning be slightly different?

Comment: Since they come after, not before, they tend to be called postpositions rather than prepositions. The most common term, though, is "particle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this they are sometimes interchangeable, but are also often idiomatically used with certain verbs (a collocation).

Think of に as Ａ→Ｂ and と as Ａ↔Ｂ:

> 円をドルに両替した。
> Change yen into dollars. (I give you yen, I get dollars)
> 円をドルと交換した。
> Exchange yen for dollars (I give you yen, you give me dollars).

Comment: Would there be any situation where と would be used between yen and dollar? Ie:

円とドル❓交換した/両替した

Comment: Would you apply this analysis to cases like ～になる／～となる? I'm not sure how that works there.

Comment: @Sjiveru No, in that case the difference is, AFAIK, connected to classical Japanese; Ａになる emphasizes the result and makes the change sound simple and natural, Ａとなる emphasizes the process and makes the change sound more involved / complicated.

Comment: @Sjiveru At first I assumed this question was about what you said when I looked at the title, but it's another matter. When denoting the state after the verb makes something into, に ("to") and と ("as") are used synonymously, though と sounds more literary/formal in today's language.

Comment: @KevinBoucher 「Would there be any situation where と would be used between yen and dollar? Ie: 円とドル❓交換した/両替した」>> You can say 「円とドル**を**交換した」Lit: "exchanged yen and dollar". ← This can be interpreted as either "exchanged my yen for their dollar" or "exchanged their yen for my dollar". (And I think 「円とドルを**両替**した」 would sound a bit ambiguous or unclear; it might be interpreted as you exchanged your yen and dollar for some other currency.)